# PHP Read and Write field values without a postback

Tags: php

I want to create a hidden field in my HTML page, all good, just a simple `<input>` field.  Then, I'm trying to read the value of that input field as the page loads the first time, so the closest I've gotten to that is using a $_GET statement.  I'm simply trying to echo out the value so that I can see that it's working like such:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selection" value="fixtures">
<?php
echo $_GET['selection']
```

and that just gives me nothing, if I try:

```
echo "<h1>$_GET['selection']</h1>
```

then I get 0.

Comment: Please try `echo "<h1>{$_GET['selection']}</h1>`.

Comment: You should also escape the input string before outputting it: `htmlspecialchars($str)`. That will prevent XSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is - what `<form>` parameters you have? Did you submit form? Simples example for it will be:

```
//form.php
<form method="GET" action="next.php">
    <input type="hidden" name"selection" value="fixtures" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Send" />
</form>

//next.php
echo '<h1>'.$_GET['selection'].'</h1>';
```

You can achieve same thing with:

```
<a href="next.php?selection=fixtures">Link</a>
```

Comment: I didn't get an answer to the problem, but this at least helped to build it in such a way that it still at least works.  Thanks!